# Wallpaper App Save Button?

Tags: android, eclipse, wallpaper

Im creating a wallpaper app
and i have a set wallpaper button and all
but i want to program a Save picture button.
What code do i need to program the app to save the picture on the android device?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Look into the [WallpaperManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html) class.